# Camera in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, camera, smartphone

I try to do this project in Android Studio:
http://android-er.blogspot.ch/2010/12/camera-preview-on-surfaceview.html

I also tried to code some own projects. But there is always the same problem. My camera-object is always strikethrough.
The information is: *this inspection reports where deprecated code is used in the specified inspection scope camera*
Picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/imanM.jpg

Ideas on how to find the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The new Camera2 API is recommended these days. Unfortunately, most active devices don't support it, and never will receive a software upgrade to fix that. So, unless you are targeting newest devices, or very specific devices you can test, you are stuck with the deprecated API.